# unexpected result from cmdscale in R

Tags: r, multi-dimensional-scaling

I'm afraid I'm missing something obvious, but I just can't see what I am doing wrong.
If anyone can help me find it, please, it would be great.

Here's the full, symmetrical distance matrix I'm starting from:

```
d2 <- structure(list(P1 = c(0, 0.1, 0.3, 0.2, 0, 0.1), P2 = c(0.1, 
0, 0.5, 0.7, 1, 0.9), P3 = c(0.3, 0.5, 0, 1, 0.2, 0.3), P4 = c(0.2, 
0.7, 1, 0, 0.2, 0.5), P5 = c(0, 1, 0.2, 0.2, 0, 0.7), P6 = c(0.1, 
0.9, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -6L))

sum(abs(d2-t(d2)))
#[1] 0
```

I want to generate coordinates for the corresponding 6 points, so that the (euclidean) distance matrix resulting from those coordinates is as close as possible to my `d2`.

From the `cmdscale` documentation:

*A set of Euclidean distances on n points can be represented exactly in at most n - 1 dimensions.*

I would have thought `(n-1)/2` dimensions would suffice, and indeed, when I run `cmdscale`, if I go anywhere higher than `k=3` I get something close to 0 for the higher coordinates, or even error messages:

```
cmdscale(d2,k=3)
#            [,1]        [,2]          [,3]
#[1,] -0.03526127  0.07755701  1.708755e-05
#[2,] -0.50626939  0.31256816 -5.646907e-02
#[3,] -0.26333957 -0.40518119 -6.978213e-02
#[4,]  0.35902238  0.37455879  2.148406e-02
#[5,]  0.33997864 -0.17998635 -2.809260e-01
#[6,]  0.10586921 -0.17951643  3.856760e-01

cmdscale(d2,k=4)
#            [,1]        [,2]          [,3]          [,4]
#[1,] -0.03526127  0.07755701  1.708755e-05 -7.450581e-09
#[2,] -0.50626939  0.31256816 -5.646907e-02 -7.450581e-09
#[3,] -0.26333957 -0.40518119 -6.978213e-02 -7.450581e-09
#[4,]  0.35902238  0.37455879  2.148406e-02 -7.450581e-09
#[5,]  0.33997864 -0.17998635 -2.809260e-01 -7.450581e-09
#[6,]  0.10586921 -0.17951643  3.856760e-01 -7.450581e-09

cmdscale(d2,k=5)
#            [,1]        [,2]          [,3]          [,4]
#[1,] -0.03526127  0.07755701  1.708755e-05 -7.450581e-09
#[2,] -0.50626939  0.31256816 -5.646907e-02 -7.450581e-09
#[3,] -0.26333957 -0.40518119 -6.978213e-02 -7.450581e-09
#[4,]  0.35902238  0.37455879  2.148406e-02 -7.450581e-09
#[5,]  0.33997864 -0.17998635 -2.809260e-01 -7.450581e-09
#[6,]  0.10586921 -0.17951643  3.856760e-01 -7.450581e-09
#Warning message:
#In cmdscale(d2, k = 5) : only 4 of the first 5 eigenvalues are > 0
```

So, assuming that `k=3` is sufficient, this is what happens when I try to reverse the operation:

```
dd <- dist(cmdscale(d2,k=3),diag = T,upper = T)
dd
#          1         2         3         4         5         6
#1 0.0000000 0.5294049 0.5384495 0.4940956 0.5348482 0.4844970
#2 0.5294049 0.0000000 0.7578630 0.8710048 1.0045529 0.9013064
#3 0.5384495 0.7578630 0.0000000 1.0018275 0.6777074 0.6282371
#4 0.4940956 0.8710048 1.0018275 0.0000000 0.6319294 0.7097335
#5 0.5348482 1.0045529 0.6777074 0.6319294 0.0000000 0.7065166
#6 0.4844970 0.9013064 0.6282371 0.7097335 0.7065166 0.0000000
```

Which is quite different from what I expected:

```
as.matrix(dd)-d2
#         P1          P2          P3          P4          P5          P6
#1 0.0000000 0.429404930 0.238449457 0.294095619 0.534848178 0.384497043
#2 0.4294049 0.000000000 0.257862963 0.171004810 0.004552925 0.001306386
#3 0.2384495 0.257862963 0.000000000 0.001827507 0.477707386 0.328237091
#4 0.2940956 0.171004810 0.001827507 0.000000000 0.431929428 0.209733518
#5 0.5348482 0.004552925 0.477707386 0.431929428 0.000000000 0.006516573
#6 0.3844970 0.001306386 0.328237091 0.209733518 0.006516573 0.000000000

sum(abs(as.matrix(dd)-d2))
#[1] 7.543948
```

Has anyone got any idea why the two distance matrices don't match at all?

I could try building my own least squares problem to find the coordinates, but first I need to understand if I'm doing something wrong with these out of the box R functionalities.

Thanks!

---

**EDIT** possible inconsistency in the data found

Could the issue be that according to `d2` points 1 and 5 coincide (they have distance 0):

```
as.matrix(d2)
#      P1  P2  P3  P4  P5  P6
#[1,] 0.0 0.1 0.3 0.2 0.0 0.1
#[2,] 0.1 0.0 0.5 0.7 1.0 0.9
#[3,] 0.3 0.5 0.0 1.0 0.2 0.3
#[4,] 0.2 0.7 1.0 0.0 0.2 0.5
#[5,] 0.0 1.0 0.2 0.2 0.0 0.7
#[6,] 0.1 0.9 0.3 0.5 0.7 0.0
```

but then these two points have different distances from other points, e.g. d(1-2) is 0.1 whereas d(5-2) is 1?

Replacing the two 0's does not seem to help though:

```
d3 <- d2
d3[1,5] <- 0.2
d3[5,1] <- 0.2
dd3 <- cmdscale(as.matrix(d3),k=3)
sum(abs(as.matrix(dist(dd3))-as.matrix(d3)))
#[1] 7.168348
```

Does this perhaps indicate that not all distance matrices can be reduced to a completely consistent set of points, regardless of how many dimensions one uses?

---

**EDIT 2** possible answer to the last question.

I suspect that the answer is yes. And I was wrong on the number of dimensions, I see now why you need `N-1` rather than half that.

If I have a distance d(A-B) = 1, I can represent that in 2-1 = 1 dimensions (x axis), i.e. on a line, placing A in (xA=0) and B in (xB=1).

Then I introduce a third point C and I state that d(A-C) = 2.
I have 3 points, so I need 3-1 = 2 dimensions (xy plane).
The constraint given by d(A-C) is:

(xC - 0)^2 + (yC - 0)^2 = d(A-C)^2 = 4.

i.e. C can be anywhere on a circumference of radius 2 centred in A.
This constrains both xC and yC to be in [-2,2].

However, previously I had not considered that this constrains the possible values of d(B-C), too, because:

d(B-C)^2 = (xC - 1)^2 + (yC - 0)^2

thus, by substitution of the (yC - 0)^2 term:

d(B-C)^2 = (xC - 1)^2 + 4 - (xC - 0)^2 = -2*xC + 5

d(B-C)^2 is therefore bound to [-2*(+2)+5,-2*(-2)+5] = [1,9].

So if my distance matrix contained d(A-B) = 1, d(A-C) = 2 and d(B-C) anywhere outside [1,3], it would configure a system that does not correspond to 3 points in Euclidean space.

At least, I hope this makes sense.

So I guess my original question must be revoked.
I thought I'd leave the reasoning here for future reference or if anyone else should have the same doubt.

Answer (score 0):

Multidimensional scaling creates coordinates for the specified number of dimensions such that they will represent the distances in the original matrix as closely as possible. But the distances will be at different scales. In your example, `d3` is the original distance matrix, `dd3` is the matrix of coordinates, and `dist(dd3)` is the distance matrix from the reconstructed coordinates. The values are different, but they reflect the same relationships between points:

```
d3.v <- as.vector(as.dist(d3))  # Vector of original distances
dd3.v <- as.vector(dist(dd3))   # Vector of distances computed from coordinates
cor(d3.v, dd3.v)
# [1] 0.9433903
plot(d3.v, dd3.v, pch=16)
```

[image: Plot]

Comment: Thank you @dcarlson. Yes, I see the difference between the coordinates matrix and the distance; my doubt was more about why `cmdscale` could not make a coordinate matrix that, reconverted to distance matrix, matched exactly the original one. But I think I understand now that indeed, not all distance matrices correspond to points in Euclidean space, no matter how many dimensions one uses. I will edit the post with an example.

Comment: Yes. For example, a distance matrix could be represented in miles or kilometers. Subtracting one from the other would not produce a zero matrix. The representation of those distances is space is not unique since rotation, reflection, and translation of the origin produce different coordinate systems but the same distance matrix.